flutter_gif package giving error after i upgraded a flutter project from 3.8 to flutter 3.24
i just upgraded my flutter project from 3.8 to 3.24, kotlin to 1.9.24 and gradle to 8.4 . but i kept getting the error below. i really need to use the gif image as a welcome image after splash screen in the app and i have not been able to get another package. here is the error
"../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_gif-0.0.4/lib/flutter_gif.dart:236:8: Error: The method 'instantiateImageCodec' isn't defined for the class 'PaintingBinding'.

'PaintingBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/binding.dart' ('../../../sdks/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/binding.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'instantiateImageCodec'.
.instantiateImageCodec(data.buffer.asUint8List());
Target kernel_snapshot_program failed: Exception
2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.


Process 'command 'C:\Users\dell\development\sdks\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1 "

i have tried to get another package but couldn't see the one that fit. though its been a while since an update was released for flutter_gif package

Mostly because flutter_gif package may not be compatible with the latest flutter sdk version, you can try using https://pub.dev/packages/gif package instead.
